# Angularfire, change type from snapshotChanges always returns "value"

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

right now when calling the following code using the Angularfire extension:

```
this.db.doc(path).snapshotChanges();
```

Angularfire retrieves a DocumentSnapshot and a type that is always equal to "value" regardless of the real change type, I wonder if there's a workaround or how can I actually get the change type in the latest version of Angularfire when fetching a document?

I also commented on a bug reported like a year ago but I don't fully understand one of the comments made by a member, please follow this link:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1762#issuecomment-413929560

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you

```
this.db
  .collection('collectionName')
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(snapshots => snapshots.map((action: DocumentChangeAction<any>) => {
      return {
        ...action.payload.doc.data(),
        id: action.payload.doc.id,
        type: action.type
      };
    }))
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

base on the official document, you can use the `snapshotChanges()` with change type.

```
this.db.doc(path).snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(map(schedules => console.log(schedules.type)));
```

[image]

Comment: That's for an angular collection, I'm talking about single angular documents