# Does Firestore on web charge two reads for two listeners?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

Using Firestore Web API v9, suppose I have a collection listener and a document listener for a document in that collection. An update for that document comes through.

Two questions:

1. Am I charged for two reads?
2. Is this an acceptable practice in general? Does the SDK send the data back twice, or send it once and dispatch an update twice?

Example:

```js
collectionSnapshots(collection(firestore, 'people')).subscribe(...);

docSnapshots(doc(firestore, 'people/john')).subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Am I charged for two reads?

You are charged for number of documents being read irrespective of number of listeners you have. If 'people' collection has 50 documents and the listener returns 50 docs, you are charged 50 reads. Any updates received later will be charged 1 read per update.

> Does the SDK send the data back twice, or send it once and dispatch an update twice?

When the listener is added, it'll return all documents that matched your query (in this case, the complete people collection). After that, whenever a document is added/updated/deleted the update will be received by listener.

Yes, if you have a listener on people collection and another listener on a document of that collection. Both the listeners will fetch updated data and you'll be charged 2 reads for that single update. You don't need another listener just for a single document though. You can read document ID from changes received and update it in your web app.

```
import { collection, query, where, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "people"));

const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
    if (change.type === "modified") {
      // a document in people collection is modified
      const docId = change.doc.id; 
      const docData = change.doc.data();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Got it, thank you! I ask in the context of having an Angular component that displays data about a single person. Is it somehow possible to get a stream of updates about `people/john` from the `people` collection listener (something like getCachedDocSnapshots()), or do I have to maintain that local cache manually?

Comment: @mdierker yes, the code snippet in my answer is a listener on people collection. If the documeny john is updated, it should trigger the function in onSnapshot and contain data of John's document. For AngularFire, you can get the `change.type` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567390/angularfire-change-type-from-snapshotchanges-always-returns-value/55567772). Essentially, collection listener will trigger for any document in the collection, you just need to read the document ID and change type and perform any action.

Comment: I think I'm understanding correctly! It seems like I shouldn't have every individual Person component subscribe to the whole `people` collection though, which means I need some sort of in-app dispatch system to notify a `Person` component when there's an update for `john` (i.e. the body of your listener snippet). I was hoping to somehow leverage Firestore's SDK for that rather than implementing it manually.

Comment: @mdierker Yes, that's correct. The listeners can provide you updated data for each document but you'll have to manually update it wherever required (it's different for every use case again so nothing much Firebase SDK can do about that).